# PyPDF returning Junk encodes

Tags: python, data-mining, codec, pypdf, hindi

I have been trying to extract text from a PDF file containing text in Hindi (Devanagari) and stored the value in a text file.

Can you help me with extracting Hindi text from the PDF using PyPDF2 instead of **pdfminer** and other tools?

This is my recent code that gives error:

```
import PyPDF2 as ppdf
import codecs

pdfobj=open('hindi.pdf',mode='rb')
    pdfread = ppdf.PdfFileReader(pdfobj)
    page=pdfread.getPage(1)
    text=page.extractText().encode('utf-8')
    print(text)
```

but this returns junk values like this:

```
204 0,*L  !*+,-./, 0(1,#.23)#*+ ,#- @'#7<1593=? @'#7< :2
```

Comment: `text=page.extractText().encode('utf-')` -> `text=page.extractText().encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: It was just a typo there, the actual code had 'utf-8'.

Comment: @thanatoz-Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a recent version of a `pypdf`:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```